# Can't upload files to home server from some computers

Tags: php, file-upload, apache2

Recently I've installed small server at home with Ubuntu OS and XAMPP. Now I have simple PHP-based interface to upload PDF files to server and run shell script to extract pages from it. It works perfectly from my local network (access by local IP), from home internet (access by external IP) and even from mobile internet via android phone (by external IP). But it doesn't work neither from my work internet, nor from my wife's work internet (the most important).

The problem is file cannot be uploaded. Web page just "thinks" infinitely, no errors is reporting, I don't even know where to dig and who to blame. The rest of the script works fine with already uploaded PDF files.

Please help, at least where I should start looking?

Here is part of PHP script (don't sure if it will help):

```
if(isset($_POST["act"])) {
    if($_POST["act"]=="get"){
        if(isset($_FILES["upl"])&&$_FILES["upl"]["name"]!=""){
            if(getExt($_FILES["upl"]["name"])!=="pdf") {
                $err=1;
            }
            else {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upl"]["tmp_name"],"pdfs/".$_FILES["upl"]["name"])) $file=$_FILES["upl"]["name"];
                else $err=2;
            }
        } elseif(isset($_POST["file"])) {
            if(file_exists("pdfs/".$_POST["file"])) $file=$_POST["file"];
            else $err=3;
        }
        if($file) {
            if(!isset($_POST["fp"],$_POST["lp"])||!is_int((int) $_POST["fp"])||!is_int((int) $_POST["lp"])) {
                $err=4;
            } else {
                $pg=array($_POST["fp"],$_POST["lp"]);
                if(isset($_POST["nname"])&&$_POST["nname"]!="") {
                    $output=$_POST["nname"];
                    if(getExt($output)!=="pdf")$output.=".pdf";
                } else {
                    $exts=getExt($file,"");
                    $output=$exts[1]."_($pg[0]-$pg[1]).".$exts[0];
                }
                $doGS="./gs.sh \"pdfs/$file\" \"pdfs1/$output\" $pg[0] $pg[1]";
                $doGS=`$doGS`;
                if(file_exists("pdfs1/".$output)) header("location: result.php?res=$output");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

File Uploads section in `php.ini`:

```
file_uploads=On
upload_tmp_dir="/opt/lampp/temp/"
upload_max_filesize=128M
```

Permissions to `temp` folder is 777.

HTML form data:

```
<form action="procc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>Choose uploaded file or upload a new one:</div>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow-y: scroll;">
<table width="100%">
<tr><td><div><label><input onchange="chfile(this.value)" type="radio" name="file" value="1.Вентиляторы.pdf" />1.Вентиляторы.pdf</label></div></td><td><a target="_blank" href="pdfs/1.Вентиляторы.pdf">[open]</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>Upload new PDF file: <span style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="file" name="upl" accept="application/pdf" /></span><br />
(If both [new file to upload] and [file from list] is set, then file from list will be ignored)
</div>
<hr width="400" align="left" />
<div>Chosen file (from list): <span id="chosen"></span></div>
<div>First and last page: <input type="text" size="4" name="fp" /> - <input type="text" size="4" name="lp" /></div>
<div>New filename: <input type="text" size="10" name="nname" /></div>
<div>(last field can be ignored, in this case name will be based on the original filename)</div>
<div><button name="act" value="ext">Extract pages</button></div>
</form>
```

`error_log` file on Apache reboot:

```
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:31.064659 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2339] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:38.243555 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2857] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:38.243843 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2857] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:38.243957 2013] [suexec:notice] [pid 2857] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:38.625858 2013] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2858] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:39.123570 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2858] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:39.123708 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2858] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:39.123844 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2858] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:39.157999 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2858] AH00163: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 23 20:03:39.158180 2013] [core:notice] [pid 2858] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
```

I've opened all ports (1-65535) on my server, and now it works fine from my workplace's network, but I don't really like this solution. Can someone give me an advice on which ports to keep opened?
Before now I had four ports opened: for HTTP, SSH and two for FTP.

Comment: Maybe there are firewall restrictions in your workplaces preventing uploads like this?

Comment: Could be different things like, server config, pdf file is to big, etc. Try uploading a small image just to debug the cause.

Comment: Your code is not exactly secure. You at least check for .pdf extensions, but you're blindly using the user-supplied `['name']` parameter, allowing a malicious user to scribble pdf files **ANYHWERE** on your server.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb, the same pdf files can be easily uploaded to other public servers (email servers, for example)

Comment: ok, that blows that theory then ... might be worth checking out all the values in the php.ini file just to make sure there's nothing in there preventing access or restricting filesizes etc. I know by default there's a 2Mb upload limit in there.

Comment: Can you check your apache access logs? See if any requests are even hitting your server from the ip your having problems with. If they're there, check your apache error log. Also make sure display_errors is on in your php.ini, or else youll never see the error at all.

Comment: @xlordt, things are strange... Empty PDF (845 bytes) was easily uploaded and went to `pdfs` folder; 1kB-32kB PDFs looks like uploaded (page reloads), but actually not; PDFs>32kB hangs page for ever. Next step: unplug LAN cable and plug my phone to the same computer to use mobile internet instead of workplace's. All of the above PDFs (and some others, more 'heavy') uploaded with no problem.

Comment: ok, what happens if you just print out the array (print_r ($_FILE)) with out moving the file (make sure its not /tmp)? what kind of server are we talking about? did you check all server configurations like php.ini for example?

Comment: @FrankvanLuijn, yes, apache gets requests (both POST and GET, depending on `access_log`), and also proceed requests if they don't include files to upload (can manipulate with already uploaded files). `error_log` (if this is apache's log file) says nothing on that. `php.ini` has `display_errors=On`

Comment: @xlordt, corrections in code (posted in question: commented `move_uploaded_file` and last page redirection lines and add `print_r($_FILES)` instead of the first one) made no difference, it seems like script doesn't even get to that lines, stopped by file uploading process.  "what kind of server are we talking about?" - don't really know what it means (I'm newbie "home-made" sys. admin). Physically this is a x86 computer with Atom processor, OS - Ubuntu Desktop with XAMPP installed (Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc.) configs (like php.ini) are on defaults, and I don't really know what to check.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, open php.ini and locate file upload options see what you see there.. also have you tried another pdf file?

EDit: oh.. nm I see you did.. sec let me try your script out, would you mind updating your post with html please

Comment: @MarcB, yes, thank you, there is too much to be improved in my scripts, but major problem is different yet.

Comment: @xlordt, sure, in several minutes (need to translate interface into English).

Comment: also link me to your pdf file if its not a confidential file... but first I need to see your form.. your error might be cause by post_max_size as well... I forgot about this.. but sitting here wondering made me remember :P

Comment: @xlordt, here is link to page itself: [link](http://89.178.153.124/pdfcut/index.php). `post_max_size=128M` - the same as upload file size. Pdf file is really the random one (I've already left my workplace with all PDFs I've tried), like one already uploaded.

Comment: hmm interesting cause.. so if you remove all your php code and just leave the print_r ($_FILES) what do you get again? just leave the print_r nothing more, nothing less. I also downloaded your file and it gave me errors but it was due to the files name, since I am on a different locate.

Comment: Its a strange problem indeed. Just two quick thoughts, have you checked the post_max_size in your ini which limits the maximus size of post-requests? Second thing I could think is maybe some functions don't like the charset your using? No idea which one though..

Comment: @xlordt, just came to my workplace... so, yes, just leaving `<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>` in PHP script gave no result: page just hanging. But one more detail: When I try to upload file by Chrome browser, it shows upload progress, and it stops at 21% in 154kB file and at 84% in 38kB file - both cases is about 32kB. But `temp` folder is empty during upload process (I don't really sure if there should appear something). Can it be some port's problem? Like my workplace's server redirect file transfers out from standard HTTP port (80) to something else?

Comment: @FrankvanLuijn, yes, mentioned `post_max_size` in second post before your's. And just tried to upload file with English content - same issue.

Comment: hmm with out trying this out my self to check out server specs, I think that I am out of results. Is there anything in the log files?/

Comment: @xlordt, when I try to upload file `access_log` says: `"POST  /pdfcut/procc.php HTTP/1.1" 302 16` (what does last numbers mean?). Also I've noticed some changes in `error_log` file on Apache reboot, but also don't know what them means. I'll print them in question body in a moment.

Comment: its a redirection code. check the rtf, or search google for more info.. or read http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/302-redirect/

Comment: @xlordt, I see, thank you. And I've found out that the last number is amount of data sent. I hope there is no useful information because I have no idea on what's going on with HTTP statuses: when I try to access PHP script with it's standard content, HTTP status is 302, when I change it with only `print_r($_FILES)` it gets status 200 (coincidence?..) (but still file cannot be uploaded). Now I'll upload one file with none-Cyrillic encoding to get rid of encoding thoughts and then will go home...